# Print statement causing 500 response

Tags: django, python-3.x

```
def gettable(request):
    reqdata = request.POST
    data = reqdata['dataabc']
    # print data
    return HttpResponse("OK")
```

This works, but as soon as I uncomment `print data`, I see a `500` response in my dev console.

Why could this be happening? I just need to print a couple of things to the console to test.

Comment: what do you mean by `filterlist` (code incomplete)?

Comment: Sorry, I meant uncomment `print data`

Comment: could you add the 500 response from the dev console? may help.

Comment: also, what version/flavor of python are you using?

Answer (score 2):

### python 3

[In python 3, `print` is a function.](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function)
Using `print` as a statement will fail and raise an exception which will terminate your view function prematurely and cause an error `500`.

### logging module

`print` is bad practice in libraries and in server-side / background tasks code. please use the `logging` module instead. django even has a [section for how to configure and use `logging` properly](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/).

### mod_wsgi and print

https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/DebuggingTechniques

Prior to `mod_wsgi` version 3.0, you would see this when using `print` with `sys.stdout`:

```
IOError: sys.stdout access restricted by mod_wsgi
```

and you would need to explicitly use a file, e.g.:

```
print >> sys.stderr, data  # python 2
```

You can however disable the restriction by editing your configuration and using the `WSGIRestrictStdout` directive.

Answer (score 0):

Completely agree with dnozay. Logging module is a way to go.

More about print statements with wsgi:
http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2009/04/wsgi-and-printing-to-standard-output.html?m=1